# How would I give different name to inputs in the switch statement, which is used to display different types of question

Tags: php, html

The problem is that if I assign same case type, which is used for different types of question inputs too 2 different question. I am able to only select 1 question at a time. The question types are saved within the database. I think I need to change the name attribute for every input but I am not sure how to do it.

I have tried using a for loop inside the switch statement for a that specific type of input.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) 
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo <<<_END
    <label for="questions"><h2>{$row['question_id']} 
        {$row['question_body']}</h2></label><br>
_END;
    switch ($row['question_type']) 
    {
       case "DD":
        echo 
    "<select name = 'answer[]'>
       <option>Facebook</option>
       <option >Instagram</option>
       <option>Snapchat</option>
       <option>Other</option>
    </select><br>";
    break;
    case "NI":
         echo "<input type = 'text' pattern= '[0-9]' title = 'Please enter a number between 0-9' name= 'answer[]' required><br>";
    break;
    case "RI":
    echo "<input type = 'radio' name = 'answer[]' value = 'Yes' required>Yes<br>
    <input type = 'radio' name = 'answer[]' value = 'No'>No<br>"; 
    break;
    case "TXT":
    echo "<input type = 'text' name = 'answer[]' required>";
    break;
    case "CB":
    echo "<input type = 'checkbox' name = 'answer[]' value = 'Smart Phone'> Smart Phone<br>
     <input type = 'checkbox' name = 'answer[]' value = 'Laptop'> Laptop<br>
    <input type = 'checkbox' name = 'answer[]' value = 'PC'> PC<br>";
    break;
    }

    echo <<<_END

<input type = 'text' name = 'question_id[]' value='{$row['question_id']}'><br>

_END;}
```

I do get all the different types of questions but they all have the same name so if I edit case RI, which is for radio input, then all the question types, that are radio inputs will be deselected and only one radio input will be selected inside the form.

Comment: you question would be much more understandable if you showed the input and the formatted HTML you have as output

Comment: I assume you could have a counter and have `answer[$cnt]` and add to the counter every time you loop

Comment: how would I store different names for CB input question type, since the user can select multiple answers for that specific type of input

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use some PHP  with the strings that make the checkoxes and selects to have unique names for each one of them

for ex.

```
 echo 
    "<select name = 'answer".$i."[]'>
       <option>Facebook</option>
       <option >Instagram</option>
       <option>Snapchat</option>
       <option>Other</option>
    </select><br>";
```